# How to limite foreach loop

Tags: php, html, laravel

### How to print limited data with `FOREACH`

---

I have 10 data in db but, i want to print only first 3 data with `foreach`.
Also i tried and used `array_slice()` method, but next i got some errors.

Thank you!

```
@foreach($products as $_product) 
  //there is Html code... with variables
@foreach
```

I tried : `@foreach(array_slice($products, 0, 2) as $_product)`. and i got:

> array_slice() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given.

Comment: well.. a `foreach` is *designed* to iterate *each* element. but have you tried incrementing a counter, and `break`ing the loop if you're above your limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `limit(3)` in your eloquent or `take(3)`
Or if you need to make it in blade use `$loop` variable
Like this

```
@if($loop->iteration <=3)
  @continue
```

Or in your controller

```
Product::limit(3)->get();
Product::take(3)->get();
```

If u use it in controller there will be no need to check in your blade view

Answer (score 0):

Just use the @break; statement once you've printed however many you want - it will jump you out of the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

so something quick i can think of this:

```
@foreach($products as $_product) 
  //there is Html code... with variables
  @if($loop->iteration == 3) //Thanks to the response of @MohammedAktaa
      @break
  @endif
@foreach
```

**Although I think it should be best to limit the results from the query to the database.**

[Ordering, Grouping, Limit, & Offset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: Thanks @MohammedAktaa I did not know the existence of the variable $loop.